# Proof Sets are indepentent

Tags: probability

How do i proof that two Sets: A and B are indepentend if $P(A|B) = P(A|\overline{B})$

$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$
$ = P(A|\overline{B}) = \frac{P(A \cap \overline{B})}{P(\overline{B})}$

$ \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A \cap \overline{B})}{1- P(B)}   \  \  \  \  \ |  * 1 - P(B)$

$\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} * (1 - P(B)) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} - P(B) \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = P(A \cap \overline{B}) \ | * P(B)$

$P(A\cap B ) - P(B) P(A\cap B ) =  P(A \cap \overline{B})  P(B) \ | +  P(B) P(A\cap B ) $

$P(A\cap B ) = P(A \cap \overline{B})  P(B) + P(B) P(A\cap B ) = P(B) [P(A \cap \overline{B}) + P(A\cap B )] $

---

---

$P(A \cap \overline{B}) + P(A\cap B ) = P(A)$

---

---

$P(A\cap B ) = P(B) [P(A)] $

per definition $P(A\cap B )$ is only $ = P(A)P(B)$ if A and B are indepentend

is this proof done right?

Answer (score 1):

$$P(A) = P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|\bar B)P(\bar B)= P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|B)P(\bar B)$$

$$ = P(A|B)[P(B)+P(\bar B)] = P(A|B)$$